# @ApiModelProperty Swagger-Mvc

Tags: spring, swagger

Hello guys I have a problem with swagger-mvc (version 0.9.5).

I have the following restcontroller:

CanvasController.java (snippet)

```java
/**
 * The Class CanvasController.
 */
@Api(description = "Operations for canvases", value="canvascontroller")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/canvas")
public class CanvasController {


  ...

  @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "No problem occurred.")
  })
  @ApiOperation(value = "Returns all canvases.", notes = "Returns all canvases.", response = Canvas.class, responseContainer = "List")
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/all", "", "/"}, method = {        RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity < List < Canvas >> getAll() {
    return new ResponseEntity < List < Canvas >> (canvasService.findAll(),
      HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}
```

Canvas.java

```java
package cloudincubator.canvas.db;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

/**
 * The Class Canvas.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Canvas", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"C_Id"})})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@canvasId")
@ApiModel(value = "Canvas", description = "Represents a canvas in the database.")
public class Canvas
 {

    /** The {@link CanvasGroup} to which this Canvas belongs. */
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "C_Canvas_Group_Id", referencedColumnName = "CG_Id", nullable = true)
    private CanvasGroup ccanvasgroup;

    /** The description of this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Description")
    @ApiModelProperty(value="Description")
    @JsonProperty("TEST")
    private String cdescription;

    /** The x position in the CanvasGroup grid. */
    @Column(name = "C_GridX")
    @ApiModelProperty(value="GridX")
    private Integer cgridx;

    /** The y position in the CanvasGroup grid. */
    @Column(name = "C_GridY")
    @ApiModelProperty(value="GridY")
    private Integer cgridy;     

    /** The height of this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Height")
    private Integer cheight;

    /** The path of the icon which belongs to this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Icon")
    private String cicon;

    /** The identifier of this Canvas. */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "C_Id", table = "Canvas")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long cid;

    /** The name of this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Name")
    private String cname;

    /** The shortcut of this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Shortcut")
    private String cshortcut;

    /** The {@link Sticker Stickers} which belong to this Canvas. */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="scanvas")   
    @Column(nullable = true)    
    private List<Sticker> cstickers;

    /** The width of this Canvas. */
    @Column(name = "C_Width")
    private Integer cwidth;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Canvas.
     */
    public Canvas(){}

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Canvas with the given identifier .
     *
     * @param cId : The identifier of this Canvas.
     */
    public Canvas(Long cId)
    {
        this.cid = cId;
    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Canvas with the given name.
     *
     * @param cName : The name of this Canvas. 
     */
    public Canvas(String cName) {       
        this.cname  = cName;
    }   

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) return true;
        if ( !(other instanceof Canvas) ) return false;

        final Canvas canvas = (Canvas) other;

        if ( !canvas.getCId().equals( getCId() ) ) return false;        

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link CanvasGroup} to which this Canvas belongs.
     *
     * @return the {@link CanvasGroup}.
     */
//  @ApiModelProperty(position=1, required = true, hidden = false, dataType="cloudincubator.canvas.db.CanvasGroup")
    public CanvasGroup getCCanvasGroup() {
        return ccanvasgroup;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the description of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the description of this Canvas.
     */ 
    public String getCDescription() {
        return cdescription;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the x position in the CanvasGroup grid of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the x position in the CanvasGroup grid of this Canvas.
     */
    public Integer getCGridX() {
        return cgridx;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the y position in the CanvasGroup grid of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the y position in the Canvasgroup grid of this Canvas.
     */
    public Integer getCGridY() {
        return cgridy;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the height of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the height of this Canvas.
     */
    public Integer getCHeight() {
        return cheight;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the path of the icon which belongs to this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the icon path of this Canvas.
     */
    public String getCIcon() {
        return cicon;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the identifier of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the identifier of this Canvas.
     */
    public Long getCId() {
        return cid;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the name of this Canvas.
     */
    public String getCName() {
        return cname;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the shortcut of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the shortcut of this Canvas.
     */
    public String getCShortcut() {
        return cshortcut;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link Sticker Stickers} which belong to this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the {@link Sticker Stickers} which belong to this Canvas.
     */
    public List<Sticker> getCStickers()
    {
        return cstickers;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the width of this Canvas.
     *
     * @return the width of this Canvas.
     */
    public Integer getCWidth() {
        return cwidth;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    public int hashCode() {        
        return getCId().hashCode();
    }


    /**
     * Sets the {@link CanvasGroup} to which this Canvas belongs.
     *
     * @param cCanvasGroup : The {@link CanvasGroup} to set.
     */
    public void setCCanvasGroup(CanvasGroup cCanvasGroup) {
        ccanvasgroup = cCanvasGroup;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the description of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cDescription : The description to set.
     */
    public void setCDescription(String cDescription) {
        cdescription = cDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the x position in the CanvasGroup grid.
     *
     * @param cGridX : The x position to set.
     */
    public void setCGridX(Integer cGridX) {
        cgridx = cGridX;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the y position in the CanvasGroup grid.
     *
     * @param cGridY : The y position to set.
     */
    public void setCGridY(Integer cGridY) {
        cgridy = cGridY;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the height of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cHeight : The height to set.
     */
    public void setCHeight(Integer cHeight) {
        cheight = cHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the icon path of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cIcon : The icon path to set.
     */
    public void setCIcon(String cIcon) {
        cicon = cIcon;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the identifier of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cid : The identifier to set.
     */
    public void setCId(Long cid)
    {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cName : The name to set
     */
    public void setCName(String cName) {
        cname = cName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the shortcut of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cShortcut : The shortcut to set
     */
    public void setCShortcut(String cShortcut) {
        cshortcut = cShortcut;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the {@link Sticker Stickers} which belong to this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cStickers : The list of {@link Sticker Stickers} to set.
     */
    public void setCStickers(List<Sticker> cStickers)
    {
        this.cstickers = cStickers;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the width of this Canvas.
     *
     * @param cWidth : The width to set.
     */
    public void setCWidth(Integer cWidth) {
        cwidth = cWidth;
    } 
}
```

swagger output

```json
{
    "apiVersion": "1.0",
    "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
    "basePath": "/",
    "resourcePath": "/api/canvas",
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "apis": [
        {
            "path": "/api/canvas",
            "description": "getAll",
            "operations": [
                {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "summary": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "notes": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "nickname": "getAll",
                    "produces": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "consumes": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [],
                    "responseMessages": [
                        {
                            "code": 200,
                            "message": "No problem occurred.",
                            "responseModel": "List"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 401,
                            "message": "Unauthorized"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 403,
                            "message": "Forbidden"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 404,
                            "message": "Not Found"
                        }
                    ],
                    "deprecated": "false",
                    "type": "Canvas"
                },
                {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "summary": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "notes": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "nickname": "getAll",
                    "produces": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "consumes": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [],
                    "responseMessages": [
                        {
                            "code": 200,
                            "message": "No problem occurred.",
                            "responseModel": "List"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 201,
                            "message": "Created"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 401,
                            "message": "Unauthorized"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 403,
                            "message": "Forbidden"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 404,
                            "message": "Not Found"
                        }
                    ],
                    "deprecated": "false",
                    "type": "Canvas"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/api/canvas/",
            "description": "getAll",
            "operations": [
                {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "summary": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "notes": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "nickname": "getAll",
                    "produces": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "consumes": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [],
                    "responseMessages": [
                        {
                            "code": 200,
                            "message": "No problem occurred.",
                            "responseModel": "List"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 401,
                            "message": "Unauthorized"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 403,
                            "message": "Forbidden"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 404,
                            "message": "Not Found"
                        }
                    ],
                    "deprecated": "false",
                    "type": "Canvas"
                },
                {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "summary": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "notes": "Returns all canvases.",
                    "nickname": "getAll",
                    "produces": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "consumes": [
                        "application/json"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [],
                    "responseMessages": [
                        {
                            "code": 200,
                            "message": "No problem occurred.",
                            "responseModel": "List"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 201,
                            "message": "Created"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 401,
                            "message": "Unauthorized"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 403,
                            "message": "Forbidden"
                        },
                        {
                            "code": 404,
                            "message": "Not Found"
                        }
                    ],
                    "deprecated": "false",
                    "type": "Canvas"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "models": {
        "ResponseEntity": {
            "description": "",
            "id": "ResponseEntity",
            "properties": {
                "headers": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "HttpHeaders"
                },
                "body": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "statusCode": {
                    "enum": [
                        "100",
                        "101",
                        "102",
                        "103",
                        "200",
                        "201",
                        "202",
                        "203",
                        "204",
                        "205",
                        "206",
                        "207",
                        "208",
                        "226",
                        "300",
                        "301",
                        "302",
                        "302",
                        "303",
                        "304",
                        "305",
                        "307",
                        "308",
                        "400",
                        "401",
                        "402",
                        "403",
                        "404",
                        "405",
                        "406",
                        "407",
                        "408",
                        "409",
                        "410",
                        "411",
                        "412",
                        "413",
                        "413",
                        "414",
                        "414",
                        "415",
                        "416",
                        "417",
                        "418",
                        "419",
                        "420",
                        "421",
                        "422",
                        "423",
                        "424",
                        "426",
                        "428",
                        "429",
                        "431",
                        "500",
                        "501",
                        "502",
                        "503",
                        "504",
                        "505",
                        "506",
                        "507",
                        "508",
                        "509",
                        "510",
                        "511"
                    ],
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "Canvas": {
            "description": "Represents a canvas in the database.",
            "id": "Canvas",
            "properties": {}
        },
        "Void": {
            "description": "",
            "id": "Void",
            "properties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that swagger does not return the api model properties from the canvas class as you can see in the swagger output
I hope you guys can help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a couple of problems. One your action should only be annotated with a get. Secondly, one thing you may try is to remove ```response``` and ```responseContainer``` attributes in the ```@ApiOperation``` annotation and see if it helps. I suspect this may be a bug

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I've already tried to delete response and responseContainer, but it was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

**The Reason of the problem is:** there are annotations with the same name in other java files. you can look for in `@ApiModel("Name")`, and see whether the annotation exists in other files.