# @JsonValue and @ApiModelProperty conflicts

Tags: java, jackson, swagger, conflicting-libraries

in my project I am using Swagger to document REST API. I have simple value object which I want to document.

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonValue
    private String myField;

    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately, when I am adding swagger annotations and then see created documentation, there is no information about this VO.
Class with swagger annotations below:

```
@ApiModel(value = "MyClass ", description = "represents my class")
public class MyClass {

    @JsonValue
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "name", dataType = "String", example = "my field")
    private String myField;

    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    } 
}
```

Wanted to check this issue **I temporally removed *@JsonValue* annotation** and documentation was created properly, annotation *@ApiModelProperty* worked.

I cannot remove *@JsonValue* annotation permanently.

Does anybody know the solution how can I force those two tools to cooperate?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682605/apimodelproperty-swagger-mvc) answer?

Comment: This is kind of different issue, everything works fine when there is no @JsonValue annotation